# Uploading maps to QGIS cloud and control scale?

Tags: qgis-cloud

I have managed to upload my maps on QGIS but when viewing them on the web or mobile platforms I am not able to zoom out as much as I could on QGIS desktop

What could be the problem? what settings should I change so that they can be view-able and allow zooming in and out.